# how to return error through a function whose return type is int

Tags: c++, return

I have a function that reads through a file and returns sum of the numbers in the file. I am checking whether the file exists or not. if it doesn't exist, I will return 1. but my problem is the return value of my function that calculates sum is int. so if it cannot open the file it returns 1 as sum, while I want it to return 1 as an error indicator not as sum.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int sum (string filename);  

int main() {
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter the name of the input file: ";
    cin >> filename;
    cout << "Sum: " << fileSum(filename) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int sum(string filename) {
    int num = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    ifstream in;
    in.open(filename.c_str());
    if(!in.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error opening " << filename << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    in >> num;
    cout << "File contains the values:" << endl;
    while(in.good()) {
       sum += num;
       cout << num << " ";
       in >> num;
    }
    if(!in.eof()) {
       cout << "Error" << endl;
       return 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: it returns -1 on error

Comment: But when it cannot open the file it displays sum=1.

Comment: Right, because that's what your code does.

Comment: It's common to return -1 on error, so you can change these lines in your code: `cout << "Error opening " << filename << endl; return 1;` and return `return -1`;

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on what the valid inputs (e.g. the values in the file) are, and what the implications of an error are on your program (e.g. if a sum cannot be computed, can the program sensibly continue anyway?).

For example, if you can guarantee that the data in any file contains only positive values, you might choose to return a negative value to indicate an error (e.g. `-1` to indicate a problem opening the file, `-2` to indicate a negative value in the file, `-3` to indicate that the sum of values in a file is larger than can be stored in an `int`, etc etc).

Unfortunately, that sort of "some return values valid, others indicate error" doesn't work if any set of values (positive and negative) can be in the file.  For example, if there is a possibility of a single value of `1` in the file, clearly `1` can not be used to report an error.  Similarly, if there is a mix of positive and negative values, there is no particular value you can return to indicate an error.

In that circumstance, options include

- Function returns an error indicator only, and accepts an additional argument to hold the result

  ```
  int DoSum(const std::string &file, int &sum)
  {
      /* return value of zero indicates a sum has been computed
            other values indicate an error status
      */
  }
  ```
- Function returns a data structure that holds two values

  ```
  struct ReturnData
  {
        int sum;
        int error_indicator;
  };

  struct ReturnData DoSum(const std::string &file)
  {
  }
  ```
- Function returns a sum but throws an exception on an error

  ```
  int DoSum(const std::string &file)
  {
       /*  do calculations */
       if (error_has_occurred)
           throw some_appropriate_exception();
       else
           return calculated_sum;
  }
  ```

The first two cases have the advantage that the caller doesn't need to do anything if the error is non-critical to the program and the corresponding disadvantage that the caller can forget to check if an error has occurred.

The third case has the advantage that, if some caller (or the callers caller, etc) does not catch the exception, the program will terminate rather than continuing with bad data.   It has the disadvantage that, if an error condition is non-critical, the caller is forced to catch the exception, regardless.

Generally speaking, therefore, an exception should not be thrown unless it is absolutely mandatory that the cause of the error condition be corrected if the program is to continue executing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to use the return value to give a result **and** indicate an error you have to pick values that don't overlap. If 1 is a valid sum there is no way to also use 1 to indicate an error. That's one of the reasons that exceptions were invented. An exception can't be mistaken for a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

It is suboptimal to return a magic value to signalize something gone wrong, because the sum of elements in the file could be any value and by a coincidence exactly this same magic value.

There are following possibilities to indicate something went wrong

1. using exceptions. This reduces the danger, that the problem will be overlooked by the user. But sometimes it is "normal" that the file is not there, so one would not like to throw an exception because it is not that exceptional after all.
2. using [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) or a self-made struct which contains an error code next to the result as returned value. But the error code is easier to overlook as an exceptions.
3. using a dedicated error flag `int sum(string filename, int &errorFlag)`, the main problem of this approach is that it litters the code with initialization of the error flag prior to the call of sum, making it harder to understand.
4. storing the error code in a global variable, which can be queried after the call to `sum`. But you can be pretty sure, nobody will check this value, because nobody reads documentation these days.